# Error 1064 when importing SQL generated from MySQL Workbench forward engineering

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to import a schema into MySQL (MariaDB 10.1.36) and I am getting the above error. I also tried direct forward engineering in MySQL Workbench but the results are the same.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')
>   ENGINE = InnoDB

Sample code that fails is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`adhere` (
  `adhere_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_uuid` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adhere_id`),
  INDEX `ix_tmp_autoinc` (`adhere_id` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 19
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

I tried changing the backticks into single quotes in vain, I later removed them to same result. The expectation is to have the table created so do the rest structured like so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `VISIBLE` word

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4f012250df542cb5cb9b863abf1c7ffe)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `example`.`adhere` 
(
  `adhere_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `id_uuid` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`adhere_id`),
  INDEX `ix_tmp_autoinc` (`adhere_id` ASC) 
)
```

Comment: Needed MySQL 5.7 to get it working, MariaDB was no good for that.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your version of mariadb supports invisible/visible indexes here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/ and if not turn off the option in mysql workbench here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-table-editor-indexes-tab.html